# How to exclude email where first date_reg <2016-02-01 with using the aggregate min ()

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Query1**

```
#standardSQL
WITH qualified AS (
SELECT user_id, email
FROM test.users 
GROUP BY user_id, email
#HAVING MIN(date_registration) > '2016-04-01 00:00:00'
)
SELECT u.email, SUM(s.price) AS sum_price
FROM qualified AS u
JOIN test.sales AS s ON u.user_id=s.user_id
JOIN test.lesson AS l ON u.email=l.email
GROUP BY u.email
```

[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMvvA.png)

**Query2**

```
#standardSQL
WITH qualified AS (
SELECT user_id, email
FROM test.users 
GROUP BY user_id, email
HAVING MIN(date_registration) > '2016-04-01 00:00:00'
)
SELECT u.email, SUM(s.price) AS sum_price
FROM qualified AS u
JOIN test.sales AS s ON u.user_id=s.user_id
JOIN test.lesson AS l ON u.email=l.email
GROUP BY u.email
```

[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7soJ.png)

email_1 as a result2 should be completely absent since it has the     min(date_registration) > '2016-04-01 00:00:00'. How to do it?

**Query3**

```
 #standardSQL
 WITH qualified AS (
 SELECT user_id, email,date_registration
 FROM test.users 
 GROUP BY user_id, email,date_registration
 #HAVING MIN(date_registration) > '2016-04-01 00:00:00'
)
SELECT u.email, SUM(s.price) AS sum_price,date_registration
FROM qualified AS u
JOIN test.sales AS s ON u.user_id=s.user_id
JOIN test.lesson AS l ON u.email=l.email
GROUP BY u.email,date_registration
```

**Result3**

```
email   sum_price   date_registration
email_2 1000    2016-04-21 15:00:00 UTC  
eamil_2 1000    2016-06-08 15:00:00 UTC  
eamil_2 1000    2016-05-02 15:00:00 UTC  
email_1 1000    2016-05-02 15:00:00 UTC  
email_1 1000    2016-03-02 15:00:00 UTC
```

Table structure:

**test.users**

- user_id
- date_reg
- email

**test.lesson**

- email

**test.sales**

- price
- user_id

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select u.email, sum(s.price) as sum_price,
from test.users u join
     test.sales s
     on u.user_id=s.user_id join
     test.lesson l
     on u.email = l.email
group by u.email
having min(date_reg) >= '2016-02-01';
```

Comment: No. Query returned zero records. But there are suitable records in the database. If you use the following query `where u.email not in (select email from test.users where date_reg < '2016-02-01 00:00:00')` the required result will be displayed. But the question is how to get the same result using the aggregate min ()

Comment: @mixail . . . It is not clear why this would be returning zero records, unless all the `date_reg` values were before 2016-02-01, or the joins failed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

try below for BigQuery StandardSQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH qualified AS (
  SELECT user_id, email 
  FROM test.users 
  GROUP BY user_id, email
  HAVING MIN(date_reg) >= '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
)
SELECT u.email, SUM(s.price) AS sum_price
FROM qualified AS u
LEFT JOIN test.sales AS s ON u.user_id=s.user_id
LEFT JOIN test.lesson AS l ON u.email=l.email
GROUP BY u.email
```

As you can see it leaves your query as is - but instead narrows down `test.users` table into `qualified` table

Comment: This is almost what i need. But email is not completely excluded. I need to completely exclude email from the list if the first date_reg> = 2016-02-01. Could you tell me what needs to be supplemented?

Comment: @mixail - based on query in my answer  - it should be excluded - can you give a little more details/example?

Comment: @mixail - btw - you meant `exclude if first date_reg < 2016-02-01` - correct?

Comment: @mixail - can you show example of rows for email_1 with date_reg < '2016-02-01 00:00:00' ? Btw, you queries examples (Query1 and Query2  and question after them) do not match to your question at all. Can you keep your follow-ups consistent with question please ?!

Comment: I do not think it's important. Since the date I really need is> '2016-04-01 00:00:00'. Sorry that did not immediately write it

Comment: @mixail - Date itself is not important at all - what is important is `<` or `>` which you constantly switching thus making it not clear what exactly you want! still  - provide examples of few rows for email_1 with date_reg that should be disqualified - so we can help you identify real problem!

Comment: @mixail - what is the data type of date_registration field? is it timestamp or string or else?

Comment: data type of date_registration is timestamp

Comment: @mixail - so far I don't have explanation yet why it doesn't work for you. It must. I played a little around this with dummy data and it worked for me. If you would be able to reproduce same behavior on small set of your data - this would helped us to resolve this